# Why doesn't my MacBook Air turn off?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake, google-chrome

I have a MacBook Air that the lid I left open. The screen was still on when I left it. In System Preferences, I set it to turn off the display and sleep after 10 minutes. But it didn't turn off. I know that because the next morning, all the battery ran out. Why didn't it sleep like the MacBook Air is supposed to?

**EDIT:** This is the result of the `pmset- g` command in Terminal.

```
Active Profiles: 
Battery Power -1 
AC Power 2* 

Currently in use: 

standbydelay 4200 

standby 1 

womp 1 

halfdim 1 

hibernatefile /var/vm/sleepimage 

darkwakes 1 

networkoversleep 0 

disksleep 10 

sleep 10 (sleep prevented by coreaudiod) 

hibernatemode 3 

ttyskeepawake 1 

displaysleep 10 

acwake 0 

lidwake 1 –
```

Comment: was the lid open or lid closed ? there is a sensor in the lid that might be broken.

Comment: the lid was open

Comment: With lid open any app you have could have keep it awake. Was it connected to Internet with some streaming page ? So how does it know you want it to sleep ?

Comment: It is connected to the internet with a static page I was reading. No streaming video.

Comment: If you are handy with your Mac, open the Terminal app and type "pmset -g" then copy and paste the results here.

Comment: Active Profiles:
Battery Power  -1
AC Power  2*
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10 (sleep prevented by coreaudiod)
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1

Comment: So it's stopped by `coreaudiod`?

Comment: there you go, now you know :) it was playing or trying to play something !

Comment: to get more details about it type "pmset - g assertions"

Comment: Why is coreaudiod active?

Comment: "Coreaudio" is your audio device. Something  was using it. Did you had any music running?

Comment: no music running. just a webpage I was reading. the volume was at 5 dots and no sound was going.

Comment: did you try the"pmset -g assertion" to see the result?

Comment: Error: unhandled argument assertion
Usage: pmset <options>
See pmset(1) for details: 'man pmset'

Comment: sorry, i made a typo , not wonder it is 105 F (41 C) here. the correct command is "pmset -g assertions" I missed the "s" at the end :(

Comment: pid 231(coreaudiod): [0x0000989a00010175] 06:19:05 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.audio.context91.preventuseridlesleep" 
 Created for PID: 211. 
   pid 69(hidd): [0x0000e8ce000905f7] 00:36:51 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle" 
 Timeout will fire in 578 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 26(powerd): [0x0000f10d00100185] 00:01:40 InternalPreventDisplaySleep named: "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff" 
 Timeout will fire in 199 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff

Comment: Continued: Kernel Assertions: 0x100=MAGICWAKE
   id=503  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE mod=6/30/15, 4:45 PM description=en0 owner=en0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run following command in the Terminal app it will show you what keep it from sleeping.

```
pmset -g assertions
```

Then based on the result you can take a action.

Here is a example:

```
pid 251(coreaudiod): [0x0000000100000d01] 00:17:27 NoIdleSleepAssertion named: "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,1:0'.noidlesleep" 
pid 251(coreaudiod): [0x0000000100000929] 01:11:47 NoIdleSleepAssertion named: "com.apple.audio.'BoomEngine:0'.noidlesleep"
```

In this case it was the "BoomEngine app" preventing the sleep.

In your case:

You have the "magicwake" which is keeping it from sleeping.

That could be a Bluetoot coming from headset or external keyboard(track pad), or the battery is low.

It could be also a app that you installed that would wake up on network access.